# Remove bounce on scroll in browser, issue with position:fixed div

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow

I'm trying to remove the bounce when scrolling in chrome. You'll notice the top white black is fixed and behind the second yellow block as desired.

What I need to do is remove the scroll to reveal the grey background in the browser without preventing the scroll over the top white block. Hope it makes sense

**HTML**

```
<div class="project">
</div>

<div id="content">

    <div class="warface">   
    </div><!-- END warface -->

</div><!-- END content -->
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't do this. I like playing with it. :)

Comment: could you please be a little bit more clear or provide a fiddle of what you have tried?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Please see [Unknown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871351/1715759) for a better solution.

The following is left here for historical purposes:

---

Bounce scroll in the browser is a feature of some versions of iOS / macOS.

To prevent it from happening on a website we can use the following:

**CSS**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <div id="main-container">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MvJU7/)**

Answer (score 56):

While the accepted answer works. Here is a simpler and updated version.

```
body {
    overscroll-behavior-y: none;
}
```

It does however not work for IE and Safari which is unfortunate. [Here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_overscroll-behavior) is the browser support.

Comment: Much simpler and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Appears now supported in Safari.

Comment: So much better. Great to see there is a better solution now. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

Just use this property on the body tag:

```css
body{
overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi recusandae assumenda veritatis dolorum minima deleniti accusantium optio incidunt excepturi ipsum? Recusandae praesentium ullam minima autem minus necessitatibus aperiam neque. Non sequi quibusdam perferendis magnam ab dicta omnis. Reiciendis earum ipsum adipisci voluptas ipsa rerum ipsam dignissimos vitae tempore enim saepe pariatur dicta officia odio a quasi amet magni id hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi recusandae assumenda veritatis dolorum minima deleniti accusantium optio incidunt excepturi ipsum? Recusandae praesentium ullam minima autem minus necessitatibus aperiam neque. Non sequi quibusdam perferendis magnam ab dicta omnis. Reiciendis earum ipsum adipisci voluptas ipsa rerum ipsam dignissimos vitae tempore enim saepe pariatur dicta officia odio a quasi amet magni id hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi recusandae assumenda veritatis dolorum minima deleniti accusantium optio incidunt excepturi ipsum? Recusandae praesentium ullam minima autem minus necessitatibus aperiam neque. Non sequi quibusdam perferendis magnam ab dicta omnis. Reiciendis earum ipsum adipisci voluptas ipsa rerum ipsam dignissimos vitae tempore enim saepe pariatur dicta officia odio a quasi amet magni id hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi recusandae assumenda veritatis dolorum minima deleniti accusantium optio incidunt excepturi ipsum? Recusandae praesentium ullam minima autem minus necessitatibus aperiam neque. Non sequi quibusdam perferendis magnam ab dicta omnis. Reiciendis earum ipsum adipisci voluptas ipsa rerum ipsam dignissimos vitae tempore enim saepe pariatur dicta officia odio a quasi amet magni id hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi recusandae assumenda veritatis dolorum minima deleniti accusantium optio incidunt excepturi ipsum? Recusandae praesentium ullam minima autem minus necessitatibus aperiam neque. Non sequi quibusdam perferendis magnam ab dicta omnis. Reiciendis earum ipsum adipisci voluptas ipsa rerum ipsam dignissimos vitae tempore enim saepe pariatur dicta officia odio a quasi amet magni id hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi recusandae assumenda veritatis dolorum minima deleniti accusantium optio incidunt excepturi ipsum? Recusandae praesentium ullam minima autem minus necessitatibus aperiam neque. Non sequi quibusdam perferendis magnam ab dicta omnis. Reiciendis earum ipsum adipisci voluptas ipsa rerum ipsam dignissimos vitae tempore enim saepe pariatur dicta officia odio a quasi amet magni id hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi recusandae assumenda veritatis dolorum minima deleniti accusantium optio incidunt excepturi ipsum? Recusandae praesentium ullam minima autem minus necessitatibus aperiam neque. Non sequi quibusdam perferendis magnam ab dicta omnis. Reiciendis earum ipsum adipisci voluptas ipsa rerum ipsam dignissimos vitae tempore enim saepe pariatur dicta officia odio a quasi amet magni id hic.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a simpler answer suggested here for a related question: [OSX - disable inertia scroll for "single-page" webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103125/osx-disable-inertia-scroll-for-single-page-webapp)

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Then you can't scroll.

Comment: Just in the middle of fiddling with this. It seems like you can still scroll, but you need your container `div` element to have `overscroll-y: auto;`

Answer (score 3):

Modified the solution to not create a new div in the page

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Worked for me but I didn't know if it's a good way to do

Answer (score 3):

Placing this rule on the `body` tag doesn't work in Firefox on MacOS for me, but placing it on the `html` tag does.

```css
html {
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```