# How can I remove the bounce on scroll on specific <div>?

Tags: html, browser, scroll, gradient, bounce

I am trying to remove the bounce scroll on a specific element of my page. At the moment I have a div with a gradient in a fixed position that bounces when scroll.

Is it possible to remove the browser bounce scroll on a specific div?

http://www.diegooriani.com/t3st3/img/bounce_gradient.gif

Comment: I think you need this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209223/remove-bounce-on-scroll-in-browser-issue-with-positionfixed-div

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried it before and it does work for the whole page, unfortunately it's causing a conflict with a JS that I am using to change the colour of the page as you scroll. Do you know any other solution?